# The random choice for a word from a list doesn't work properly (Python/Tkinter)

Tags: python, random, tkinter

Hello i'm working on a work on a color stroop, I can change the word and the color of the word with my code, but I can't change only the word when my function "next_selected" is called, can someone help me please ?

```
def tick():
    global doTick
    global sec
    if not doTick:
        return
    sec += 0.1
    sec = round(sec, 1)
    ftest1.after(100, tick)
    time2Label.configure(text=sec)
    if sec == 60.0:
        doTick = False
        time2Label.config(text=sec)
        label1.config(text=score, fg='black')

def start():
    global doTick
    doTick = True
    label1.pack()
    tick()
    startbutton1.destroy()

COLORS = ['blue','green','yellow','red']

def stimulus(same):

    global word
    colors = list(COLORS)

    if same:
        return (word)

    colors.remove(word)

    return (word)

def next_selected():
    global word
    word = stimulus(choice((True,False)))

    label1.config(text=word)
    label1.update()
```

Comment: Why can't you change it? What happens when you try?

Comment: Nothing, the word doesn't appear. The console knows if it's the right word, but the function for that appears the next random word doesn't work (sorry for my english)

Comment: I just don't know how to make it, i'm new on Python

Comment: What do you expect stimulus to do

Comment: All I see here are definitions, can you show how you call your functions, what you get, and what you would like to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stimulus()` is failing to pick a new color when `same=False`, nor save that new choice in the global `word`.  Give this a try:

```
COLORS = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']

word = COLORS[0]

def stimulus(same):

    global word

    if same:  # return the previous color
        return (word)

    colors = list(COLORS)

    colors.remove(word)

    word = choice(colors)  # chose a different color & remember it

    return word

def next_selected():
    global word
    word = stimulus(choice((True, False)))

    label1.config(text=word)
    label1.update()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked perfectly ! My color stroop test works know :)